# Extjs-6 MVVM architecture data binding from Ext.app.Controller?

Tags: extjs, mvvm, data-binding, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm using [MVVM architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html) of [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/) in my application. I have controller as follow(paying attention to `extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'`):

```
Ext.define('App.controller.gt.Point', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    myProp: {
        x: 'x',
        y: 'y'
    },
    init: function()
    {
        ...
    },
    activateDrawing: function()
    {
        ...
        // I want to send myProp to 'App.view.gt.Point' view and 
        // it(myProp) use binding
        var pointWin = Ext.create('App.view.gt.Point', {});
    }
});
```

if `activateDrawing` is called, controller show a window(`App.view.gt.Point` view). This window class is as follow:

```
Ext.define('App.view.gt.Point', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    ...
    controller: 'gt-point',
    viewModel: 'gt-point',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'X',

            /*
            * I want to bind the numberfield with myProp.x
            */
            bind: '{myProp.x}',

        }, {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Y',

            /*
            * I want to bind the numberfield with myProp.y
            */
            bind: '{myProp.y}',

        }]
    }],
    buttons: [{text: 'OK', action: 'OK', handler: 'onOk'}],
    ...
});
```

If numberfields `x` and `y` be changed, I want to automatically change `myProb.x` and `myProb.y`. How can implement this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Data binding and ViewController/Controller have nothing to do with each other, you can have data binding without a controller, you only need a ViewModel.

The bind configs are not defined correctly, they are like XTemplate:

```
bind : '{myProp.y}'
```

Assuming you have the myProp in your ViewModel something like this:

```
data : {
    myProp : {
       x : 'foo',
       y : 'bar'
    }
}
```

Comment: `myProp` is a `App.controller.gt.Point`(that extends `Ext.app.Controller`) property. I want to send this property to view and then config binding.

Comment: Data binding doesn't work on properties of classes, they work on the data in a ViewModel. Furthermore, out of the box, ViewModel only works bound to a component, not just any class.

Comment: But Can I send my property to component(`App.view.gt.Point`) when class initialized and add `myProp` as a component binding data?

Comment: I think it'd be best to rethink how you're doing something. Instead of doing everything on the Controller, can you have your ViewModel hold the data? Your global controller would just have to resolve your ViewModel which there are many ways you could do it.

Comment: In `App.controller.gt.Point` controller there are several views that with special condition views are created and shown.

Comment: And that's fine but the data you want to bind to, can you move that all to the ViewModel?

Comment: Why? ViewModel needs to be bound to a View, that's why it's called "ViewModel". If not, then you will have to do create your own custom code to hook it all up yourself.

Comment: before of initializing any view(such as `App.view.gt.Point`) we have to pass  some data from `App.controller.gt.Point` to it. this data are initializing in `App.controller.gt.Point`. Can I define `myProp` in viewModel and then when I want to initialize the `App.view.gt.Point`, initialize `myProp` in `var pointWin = Ext.create('App.view.gt.Point', {});`?

Comment: If a view has a `ViewModel`, any child item (at any level) can have access to the `ViewModel`'s data.

Answer (score 0):

you must bind numberfield's value to myProp.x and myProp.y. also myProp must be in viewModel, not in controller.

```
Ext.define('App.view.gt.Point', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
...
controller: 'gt-point',
viewModel: {
    data:{
        myProp: {
            x: 'x',
            y: 'y'
        }
    }
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        fieldLabel: 'X',

        /*
        * I want to bind the numberfield with myProp.x
        */
        bind: {
            value:'{myProp.x}'
        }

    }, {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Y',

        /*
        * I want to bind the numberfield with myProp.y
        */
        bind: {
            value:'{myProp.y}'
        }

    }]
}],
buttons: [{text: 'OK', action: 'OK', handler: 'onOk'}],
...
});
```